# How do I enforce a JSON Schema model on AWS Gateway for all requests of a certain content type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, jsonschema

I've successfully setup AWS Gateway to validate the body of incoming POST requests using JSON Schema. I was so thrilled! Hooray I thought ... as I tested the functionality using the internal AWS tools ... but then I tested a POST request w/invalid data from a website using AJAX and then a CURL request, again using invalid data - and wouldn't you know it, both of them got through to my integration and triggered my AWS Lambda function, something JSON Schema was supposed to block! I've deployed the latest API to my endpoint and even set all of the "Content-Type" headers being called to the same JSON Schema AWS model. I'm at a loss for what's going on ... how do I enforce that all requests must be one content-type or return an error?

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question for those of you who will stumble upon this issue.

By default, JQuery's ".post" method sets a Content-Type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded." The model I set in AWs Gateway was only for "application/json" POST requests. I assumed that if I set the "request validator" to use JSON Schema models for a specific content-type that only the ones I defined would allowed to pass through ... oh no, no, no! AWS Gateway conveniently let any other Content-Type pass through unchecked, bypassing my JSON Schema model validator. Unbelievable actually. So the answer to enforce only application/json was to then move to the "integration request" and configure a body mapping for application/json setting the "When there are no templates defined (recommended)" option to true. And voila, problem solved. AWS Gateway will still allow your POST request to get to this stage, but it won't get to your "action (e.g. Lambda function).

I wanted to add ... it's no longer a problem, but even by setting multiple Content-Type patterns, the model was only enforced on the first one within AWS Gateway. Strange behavior ... maybe someone could help w/this?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine using proper setting. Have your model set correctly including the validation you wish to apply. 
For your method, go to Method Execution section and set

1. Settings -> Request Validator - select option as 'Validate Body'. Your may choose other appropriate options based on your requirement.
2. Request Body -> create new entry as 'application/json' and select your model.

Done. This will work as expected and throw 500 error for other Content-Type or if model validation fails.
Also, you can always validate request in Lambda's entry function. Though that is what you want to avoid to escape lambda trigger cost.

Additional Tip: Make sure you have API Rate limit set properly as you will get charged if your API is caught by spammers/attackers, though validation through model will protect you but you will still get charged by AWS. In case of API Key set, this is still applicable.

Comment: You need to specify a body mapping in integration request for this to work. It will not work as you’ve outlined.

Comment: @CharlesSaag yes you are correct. You need to add in Integration Request -> Mapping Templates -> select never and input Content/Type( in this case 'applicaiton/json'
But just to note, things I mentioned earlier were required.

To answer the question i quickly mocked the API to verify my ans. There was no integration request for mocking, hence i missed. Thanks for correcting.